# dplyr mutate in R - add column as concat of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, concatenation

I have a problem with using `mutate{dplyr}` function with the aim of adding a new column to data frame. I want a new column to be of character type and to consist of "concat" of sorted words from other columns (which are of character type, too). For example, for the following data frame:

```
> library(datasets)
> states.df <- data.frame(name = as.character(state.name),
+                         region = as.character(state.region),
+                         division = as.character(state.division))
> 
> head(states.df, 3)
     name region           division
1 Alabama  South East South Central
2  Alaska   West            Pacific
3 Arizona   West           Mountain
```

I would like to get a new column with the following first element:

```
"Alamaba_East South Central_South"
```

I tried this:

```
mutate(states.df,
   concated_column = paste0(sort(name, region, division), collapse="_"))
```

But I received an error:

```
Error in sort(1:50, c(2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L,  : 
  'decreasing' must be a length-1 logical vector.
Did you intend to set 'partial'?
```

Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to use `sep =` not `collapse =`, and why use `sort`?. And I used `paste` and not `paste0`.

```
library(dplyr)
states.df <- data.frame(name = as.character(state.name),
                        region = as.character(state.region), 
                        division = as.character(state.division))
res = mutate(states.df,
   concated_column = paste(name, region, division, sep = '_'))
```

As far as the sorting goes, you do not use `sort` correctly. Maybe you want:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(states.df, sort))
```

This sorts each column, and creates a new `data.frame` with those columns.

Comment: Thank you Paul for your interest! I followed your suggestions and it does work with your code, but when I try to *sort* the words (I mean: `paste(sort(name, region, division), sep = '_'))`) it does not. (The same error as above in my description).

Comment: You have to read the documentation of `sort` carefully, `sort` takes a vector as input, and returns the sorted version. You feed it three vectors, which is not how you should use sort. What do you want to do precisely?

Comment: Och, ok, I understand (thank you for this explanation!). In my real case I have a dataset with 3 columns. The 3 columns stand for 3 actions that come from one *set* of actions. I no longer care about the order of how these 3 actions were taken, so I wanted to transform them into one variable - value of this variable would keep names of these 3 actions, and `sort` was intended to not take care of the order.

Comment: Thank you for all sugestions! For now I ended up with: `states.df.sorted <- as.data.frame(t(apply(states.df, 1, sort)))
names(states.df.sorted) <- c("v1", "v2", "v3")
new.column = mutate(states.df.sorted,
                    concated_column = paste(v1, v2, v3, sep = '_'))`

Comment: Or use arrange in a chain: states.df.sorted <- states.df %.% arrange(name, region, division) %.% mutate(concated_column = paste(name, region, division, sep = '_'))

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to Paul's answer. If you want to sort the rows, you could try [order](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/order.html). Here is an example:

```
res1 <- mutate(states.df,
          concated_column = apply(states.df[order(name, region, division), ], 1, 
                                  function(x) paste0(x, collapse = "_")))
```

Here order sorts the data.frame states.df by name and then breaks the tie by region and division

Comment: I used this `apply` answer for allowing mutate to paste rows by variable names! Many thanks for getting me on the right track! `mutate(tbl, var = apply(.[, c('varA', 'varB')], 1, function(x) paste(x, collapse = "")))`